# Multiple file upload using jquery uploadify

Tags: php

I have a form which used file upload. Once I pressed the uploadify button, it goes to database and displayed the name it in the form.

My question is that don't store it into the database until submit the form.. can anyone help me to upload the file by `onclick` using jQuery uploadify settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the back-end PHP processor for Uploadify to process and move the files, but then store the information in $_SESSION variables.

You can then call another script to fire in the background which inserts the $_SESSION data.

Processor file:

```
<?php

@session_start()

if (!empty($_FILES)) {  // Process uploaded file

    $upload_dir = '/path/to/uploads/';  // Set upload path WITH TRAILING SLASH

    $file_temp = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];   // Retrieve temporary file path
    $file_orig = basename( $_FILES['Filedata']['name'] ) ;  // Retrieve original file name

    $file_save = time() . $file_orig;   // Prepend filename with time stamp to avoid overwriting files
    $target_path = $upload_dir . $file_save; // Prepand filename with the upload path

    move_uploaded_file( $file_temp, $target_path ); // Move the file to the upload path using generated filename

    $insert = array(
    'path' => $file_save,
    'original' => $file_temp,
    'date_created' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    );

    $_SESSION['uploadify_files'][] = $insert; // Set session data

    echo '1'; // Success
}
```

Post processor file: (let's assume it is named "postprocess.php")

```
<?php

@session_start()

if ( is_array( $_SESSION['uploadify_files']) ) { // Process stored data

    foreach ( $_SESSION['uploadify_files'] as $one_file ) {
        // Use the data...
        $path = $one_file['path'];
        $original = $one_file['original'];
        $date = $one_file['date'];
        mysql_query(" INSERT INTO files ( path, original, date ) VALUES ('$path', '$original', '$date' ); ");
    }

    unset( $_SESSION['uploadify_files'] ); // Remove the session data so it is not processed again in the next upload
    echo 'OK'; // Report success
} else echo 'FAILURE';
```

And finally some jQuery to trigger the post processing:

```
$("#finish_button").live( "click", function(){
    $.get('postprocess.php', function(data) {
    if ( data == 'OK' ) {
        // Success !
        alert('Load was performed.');
    } else {
        // Failure
        alert('There was a problem.');
    }
    });
});
```